# Python substring won't work with number integer

Tags: python

So I am having trouble with the code in the way that it gives an error: "line 30, in 
    (ciphertextBinary[i])[x] = "0"
TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment".
 I have no idea as to why this happens as all that I am doing is changing a subtext of a string and replacing it with a string. If you can come up with any solutions it would be much obliged as I have looked for answers for a while now but have had no success. Before I had this error:

```
     if (textBinary[i])[x] == (pad[i])[x]:
        (ciphertextBinary[i])[x] = "0"
    elif (textBinary[i])[x] != pad[i][x]:
        (ciphertextBinary[i])[x] = "1"
```

the code was not working and returned the input so I changed it to what I think would make it work but have come across this error instead.

```
string = ""
string2 = ""
length = 0
lenght2 = 0
pad = ""


string = input("Enter String To Encrypt: ")
string2 = input("Enter PAD: ")

length = len(string)
length2 = len(string2)

textBinary = list(string)
pad = list(string2)
ciphertextBinary = list(string)
ciphertext = list(string)

for i in range(0, length):
    textBinary[i] = "{0:b}".format(ord(string[i]))
    for x in range(0, len(textBinary[i])):
        ciphertextBinary[i] = ciphertextBinary[i] + "a"

for i in range(0, length2):
    pad[i] = "{0:b}".format(ord(string2[i]))

for i in range(0, length):
    for x in range(0, len(textBinary[i])):
        if (textBinary[i])[x] == (pad[i])[x]:
            (ciphertextBinary[i])[x] = "0"
        elif (textBinary[i])[x] != pad[i][x]:
            (ciphertextBinary[i])[x] = "1"

for i in range(0, length):
    ciphertext[i] = int(ciphertextBinary[i], 2)
    print(chr(ciphertext[i]))
```

Comment: You can't replace individual characters in a string.  You have to replace the whole string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python does not let you change a single character within a string. Strings are considered an [immutable type](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Python_Programming/Data_Types#Mutable_vs_Immutable_Objects) in Python just like numbers or tuples. Thus, your attempt to do string assignment *within* a string is somewhat like asking to change the third digit in the number `8435` to `0`. Rather, you may be able to do something like this:

```
(ciphertextBinary[i]) = (ciphertextBinary[i])[:x] + "0" + (ciphertextBinary[i])[x+1:]
```

This works by setting your variable of interest equal to everything up to character `x`, plus the new character, plus all the characters that were after `x`.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Maybe mention strings are immutable which causes the inability of assignment

Comment: As far as I can see, your solution has fixed my problem but I have some more testing to do with it and hopefully it will work. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Strings are immutable in python. If *ciphertextBinary* is short, than the answer by jonathanking works.

If it is too long, you may want to create list first (which is mutable):

```
ciphertextBinaryL = list(ciphertextBinary)
[your last three loops]
ciphertextBinary = "".join(ciphertextBinaryL)
```